# How can regular non admin users see which G Suite package is used for their account?

Tags: google-account, account-management, google-workspace-for-business

For regular non admin users, is there a way to see which [which package](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/pricing.html) is used for their G Suite account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is that the admin tell you that someway.

The above because the licence type is only displayed on the admin console. The only indication that is given to users is that their account is a managed account.

Comment: In that case, [is there a way to find out who is the admin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136587/how-can-regular-non-admin-users-see-who-is-their-g-suite-admin)?