# How can regular non admin users see who is their G Suite admin?

Tags: google-account, account-management, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

For regular non admin users, is there a way to see who is their admin for their G Suite account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Who is my administrator?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960?hl=en)

NOTE: The above link points to a tool on the G Suite Administrator Help Center that could show who is the administrator of the account used by the user who is accessing the web page.

This is what is shown for one of my accounts managed by someone else

> > Who is my administrator?
> >     Quick definition: A person who manages Google services or devices for a company, school, or group.
>
> Your account, username@example.com, was set up by an administrator at example.com. An administrator also manages how your account works.
>
> **Help me find my administrator**
>   Your administrator is someone associated with example.com, not Google. We can’t tell you exactly who your administrator is. But here are ideas of who to ask.
>
> Your  administrator might be:
>
> - The person who gave you your username, username@example.com
> - Someone in your IT department or Help desk (at a company or school)
> - The person who manages your email service or web site (in a small business or club)